# PyMongo's insert_one() method not working using PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm, pymongo

I'm trying to use mongodb but for some reason i cant put data into a collection.
Here's my code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongo_url = "mongodb+srv://<User>:<Password>@cluster0.yozx6.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
cluster = MongoClient(mongo_url)
db = cluster["TestDatabse"]
collection = db["TestCollection"]
post = {"number": 7}
collection.insert_one(post)
```

for some reason the data the `collection.insert_one` line isn't working and it isn't giving an error message either. The program seems to get stuck on it. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it.

Comment: Have checked the logs from mongodb and that it's saying?

Comment: @MargachChris sorry I'm new to MongoDB. How do I check the logs?

Comment: It depends on how you are running it, are you running it inside a container or it's installed on your PC?

Comment: @OmarMZ You can print the `insert_one` method result as shown in the [PyMongo Tutorial](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#inserting-a-document).

Comment: @prasad_ Yes, I've tried that but nothing is printed.

Comment: @MargachChris by container, you mean like an IDE? I'm running it all on an IDE called PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different things to verify for you.

**Version compatibility:**

First of all insertOne was introduced inmongoDB 3.2, so make sure that you are connecting to a newer pymongo version, and also that the version of pymongo is compatible with your version

**Network connection:**

Make sure you have a stable connection to your DB if it is remote.
Then use:

```
result = cluster.admin.command("ismaster")
```

to check if the db is accesible, if this throws a `ConnectionError` there is a problem with the connection.

**User permissions**

Check if the user and password you are using has permissions to insert documents to the given collection.
On the mongo shell:

```
db.getRoles(
    {
      rolesInfo: 1,
      showPrivileges:true,
      showBuiltinRoles: true
    }
)
```

should show:

```
roles: [
            {
                role: "readWrite",
                db: "TestDatabse"
            }
        ]
```

for the user `User`.

**Result of insert**

Check the [result](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertOneResult). `insert_one` returns `inserted_id` and `acknowledged`.

```
res = collection.insert_one(post)
res.acknowledged # should be True
res.inserted_id
```

**Logs**

Check your logs, you can find the log path for your server by running:

```
cat /etc/mongod.conf | grep log
```