# New key, value pair in Mongodb collection using python is not getting added to the collection using update command

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

New  key, value pair in Mongodb collection using python  is not getting added to the collection using update command. Writing the code in Pycharm IDE.m

**Code**

```
match_query = {"Identifier":id,"unique id":uid}
collection.update_many(match_query,{"$set": {"key12": 12}})
```

Comment: You have a unwanted `)` in your `match_query`

Comment: that was typo. I have updated

Comment: Your syntax is correct. Try running your script from your `cmd` instead of pycharm and see the result. And in the question you mentioned "added to the collection" - I believe you mean updated?

Comment: I ran using mongo shell and executed successfully . "added to the collection" mean need to add new key value pair to the document

Comment: then how we can add new key value pair

Comment: `collection.update_many(match_query,{"$set": {"key12": 12}}, upsert=True)` - This will update the documents if they match `match_query` otherwise it will insert a new document. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Can you please specify your expected output?

Comment: {
"Identifier" : id,
"unique id" : uid,
"key12": 12

}

Comment: Then your initial query should work perfectly fine for this result. I even tested it. It works fine for me.

Comment: Also checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027381/pymongos-insert-one-method-not-working-using-pycharm-ide